# How to use external DLL in my asp.net core 2.0 project

Tags: asp.net-core, telerik, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, telerik-reporting

[image][image]

Can you please help me to solve above Error. I want use telerik.reporting dll in my current asp.net core 2.0 project. So how can i use?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the official documentation for using Telerik with .NET Core? https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-core/introduction

Answer (score 0):

Include the component using NuGet instead of a direct DLL reference.

In Visual Studio, right click on project > Manage NuGet Packages > search for Telerik.Reporting.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeiyF.png)

It's [available on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Telerik.Reporting.Services.Mvc6/).